# receiving incorrect url from amazon s3 module

Tags: 7

I am using drupal 7. I have installed amazon s3 module and its dependencies. I have created a bucket for saving my files on amazon server. Everything went good.. But when i try to get the path for the file it looks like this

http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/abc.pdf

Later i came to know the actual path must look like
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/abc.pdf

As a result i am unable to access the pdf. It always shows access Denied as a response.

Please help me to over come this.

Comment: Do you have any custom code interfering with the s3 module? If not, this is a bug report and needs to be handle on their module issue queue

Comment: No i just simply installed amazon module and AWS SDK thats it. no custom code included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a group permission for Amazon S3 in Amazon IAM and indicate who can view the bucket.

Instructions on how to grant access to your bucket here: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3VRSWZ6B3SHAV/Writing-IAM-Policies-How-to-grant-access-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal generates image caches on view, not on create/update.

When you try to hit a image that does not exists, Amazon responds you are not allowed to.

Amazon should be able to use a failover or "origin" server, to work in the "pull" instead of the "pull" mode. I have been in the phone with a couple aws reps, and they do not understand what I want, nor leave me talk with the next tech level.

For me the solution is to make image caches being generated on save, like making a simple hook or install something like imageinfo cache https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache

Answer (score 0):

The following patterns are valid for constructing S3 URLs:
http(s)://.s3.amazonaws.com/
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com//

After you need to create user and group and set permission at Amazon s3.

Pls browse your bucket, select the s3fs-public folder and choose Actions - Make Public.